# Empty space at the end of RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, linearlayoutmanager

I use LinearLayoutManager to show RecyclerView list horizontally

XML

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dailyOffersList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Code

```
dailyOffersList.adapter = DailyOffersListAdapter(dailyOffer)
dailyOffersList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

It is XML of item and it has width as wrap_content
https://codeshare.io/5XnldM

But there empty space int the end of list, and it happens only if it horizontally, like this

[image]

in the end

[image]

Comment: If you have given width to `match_parent` in row item xml file then you need to change it by `wrap_content`.

Comment: Please add your Array initialisation code and Adapter Code. Maybe there are some empty elements or some problem is Adapter.

Comment: you need to change your widget's width to `wrap_content` as suggested by piyush.

Comment: Setup the `layoutManager` first then set the `Adapter` and change width to `wrap_content` in the list row.

Comment: show your code Model Adapter Code and While updating in list code.

Comment: @Umair I have changed, doesn't help

Comment: @TigranBabajanyan then please post your adapter's xml and code here :)

Comment: @Piyush No, there wrap_content already

Comment: @Piyush, there I has one hidden loader element, which has with match_parent, I have changed it and it helped, now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `match_parent` in the xml to `wrap_content`.

`match_parent` is supposed to fill the whole with of the screen.